# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' to type 'myEntity' error

Tags: c#, casting, entitydatasource

I am using an `EntityDataSource`. I want to access the results and convert them to a List.
To do that I'm doing the following code:

```
 protected void EntityDatSrc_Selected(object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var statHistLst = e.Results.Cast<MyEntity>().ToList();
    }
```

This code I got from the question and answer here: [How to access EntityDataSource selected data programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565591/how-to-access-data-in-entitydatasource-programmatically).

I'm getting this error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' to type 'MySoluton.DAL.MyEntity'

What's causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: MyEntity is the EntitySetName and the EntityTypeFilter in the EntityDataSource HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem apperently was Entity Framework 6 which has problems with the old EntityDataSource control.

So I switched to the new EntityDataSource control and made changes according to instructions given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792144/entity-datasource-not-working-with-entity-framework-6-upgrade) in Sergey's answer and LMK's comment there. That solved the problem.